# how do i email a quiz result from google forms using app script site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need a Google script (GAS) to send an email where the student who passed the quiz on google forms can find his grade, for example if he passed the quiz and his grade is 10/10 he will receive an email on his address-email: "Hi, you've already passed your quiz and you got a 10/10"

Thank you

```
function sendEmail(e) { //respond //getRespondentEmail() 
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html"); 
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent(); 
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail(); 
  var subject = "Merci pour votre participation"; 
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that support it." 
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText }; Logger.log(emailTo); if(emailTo !== undefined){ GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I thought that when you provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: here is my script  : function sendEmail(e) {
   //respond
   //getRespondentEmail()
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
   var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
   
   var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
   var subject = "Merci pour votre participation";
   var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that support it."
   var options = { htmlBody: htmlText };
   Logger.log(emailTo);

   if(emailTo !== undefined){
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);
   }
}

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. But I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. But I think that my answer might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave my answer. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: You welcome, its okay, btw from your answer I took further information which helped me resolve my situation. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad for it. So I have a question for studying my English. I had thought that from your question, when the form is submitted, you wanted to send an email when the grade was 10/10. If my understanding was not correct, please tell me.

Comment: Hi, no I just said it for an example, what I wanted is how I email which grade from googleforms using App script. Excuse my english.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Hi, no I just said it for an example, what I wanted is how I email which grade from googleforms using App script. Excuse my english.`, I couldn't notice from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: It's okay don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Email Results of Quiz to respondent

**From the Form Trigger**

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const r = e.response;
  r.getGradableItemResponses().forEach((item,i) => {
    Logger.log('Question: %s Response: %s Score: %s',item.getItem().asTextItem().getTitle(),item.getResponse(),item.getScore());
  });
  let email = r.getRespondentEmail();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,"Quiz Response",Logger.getLog())
  Logger.log(r);
}

function createOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyFormSubmit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

**From the Spreadsheet Trigger**

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const hA = sh.getRange(1,2,1,6).getValues().flat();
  let s = '';
  hA.forEach(h => {
    s+= `\nQuestion: ${h} Answer: ${e.namedValues[h][0]}`
  });
  s += `\nYour Score is: ${e.namedValues.Score}`;
  //Logger.log(s);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],"Quiz Result",s);
}
```

Email:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the form is submitted, you want to send an email when the grade is 10/10.
- From `function sendEmail(e) {` and `var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();`, your script is the container-bound script of Google Form. And, your function of `sendEmail` is installed as OnSubmit trigger.

#### Modification point:

- In order to check `if he passed the quiz and his grade is 10/10`, it is required to calculate the grade of all items.

When this point is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this script, it supposes that the function `sendEmail` is run by the OnSubmit trigger. So please confirm whether the function `sendEmail` has already been installed as OnSubmit trigger again.

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  var maxGrade = 10; // This is from "10/10" in your question.
  var grade = e.response.getGradableItemResponses().reduce((p, e) => p += e.getScore(), 0);
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  if (grade < maxGrade || !emailTo) return;

  var subject = "Sample subject"; // Please set the subject.
  var textBody = "Hi, you've already passed your quiz and you got a 10/10.";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody);
}
```

#### Note:

- From `function sendEmail(e) {` and `var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();`, I understood that your script is the conteiner-bound script of Google Form. So please be careful about this.
- This modified script can be used by the OnSubmit trigger. So when you test this, please submit the form. When you directly run this script, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)