# how to get total score of quiz result from google forms using app script site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I made a quiz by Google form.
When a user submit his answer, Google will automatically calculate the score he gets (just as we know.)
My question is: Is there any way to get this parameter (i.e., the user's total score) in Google app script for the form?

Every related discussion ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647422/19564028), for example) I found on the internet achieve this by adding up the score of each question.
However, due to the limitation of google app script, this method doesn't work if the form contains questions of the type multiple choice grids.

Comment: About `However, every related discussion I found on the internet achieve this by adding up the score of each problem; even more unfortunately, this method seems to only work for forms that do not include multiple choice grids questions. Is there a direct way that I can get the user's score?`, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: I want to find a way to obtain the total score calculated automatically by google form in my google app script!

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I apologize; it is me whose English is poor. I've edited my post. Hopefully, this makes my problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple form with a Multiple Choice Grid as shown.  In the form script editor I created a sample script that gets the count for each row and column of the grid after multiple responses.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function getScore() {
  try {
    let form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

    // get grid items
    let choices = form.getItems()[0];
    choices = choices.asGridItem();
    let rows = choices.getRows().map( row => [] );
    let columns = choices.getColumns().map( column => column );
    console.log(columns);
    rows.forEach( row => columns.forEach( column => row.push(0) ) );
    console.log(rows);

    let responses = form.getResponses();
    for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
      let response = responses[i];
      let items = response.getItemResponses();
      for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        let item = items[j].getResponse();
        item.forEach( (row,rIndex) => {
          let cIndex = columns.findIndex( column => column === row );
          rows[rIndex][cIndex] += 1;
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(rows);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
8:11:46 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:11:50 AM  Info    [ 'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4' ]
8:11:50 AM  Info    [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
8:11:50 AM  Info    [ [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 2, 0 ], [ 1, 2, 0, 0 ] ]
8:11:48 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**References**

- [Form.getItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getItems())
- [Item.asGridItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asGridItem())
- [GritItem.getRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#getRows())
- [GridItem.getColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#getColumns())
- [Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses())
- [FormResponse.getItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses())
- [ItemResponse.getResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getResponse())

Comment: Thank you! But I am still wondering if I can get user's score of this question by functions in app script?

Comment: What do you mean by user score?  I'm not an expert on forms.

Comment: In the setting of google form, one can choose to make the form a quiz. Then, in the editor of each question, one can assign the score of the problem. In such a way, when a user submits his answer, google will automatically compute the score he gets.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to assign scores to my form to test.